# Socket.io only emitting uppercase events

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

so I wanted to try out the socket.io library and all the examples work perfectly fine (with lowercase emits). But when I try to code my one little ping->pong it doesnt emit the events (I can view the message log in firefox network tab).

Code Server (Node JS):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Socket connected");
    socket.on("ping", () => {
        console.log("PING");
        socket.emit("pong", {});
    });
});

http.listen(port, () => console.log("listening on port " + port));
```

Code in Browser:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on("pong", () => {
    console.log("recieved PONG");
});

const ping = () => {
    socket.emit("ping");
};


document.addEventListener("mousedown", ping, false);
```

Strangely, this doesn't seem to work, "Socket connected" is printed, but the sockets don't emit anything. If I change the emits and on's from "ping"->"PING" and from "pong"->"PONG" everything works perfectly fine. Im just totally confused to why this is and why the examples can use lowercase emits.

Comment: As far as i know there is no restriction about case sensitive events. Since `ping` and `pong` used by `socket.io` internally, maybe it's preventing to emit? I didn't actually examine code and i know you can listen for `ping/ping` events but i'm not sure if you can actually emit. Actually there is a suggestion about it here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md

Comment: Wow, I didnt find those restricted names when I googled. Thank you for your help, this fully answeres my question :) Please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept and you gain the reputaion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is nothing related with UPPERCASE/LOWERCASE event names, you may use them as you wish.

But `ping/pong` actually uses by socket.io server with several of them. you can see the list [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md). It's on bottom of the page =)

So unless you respest these you can use upper/lower case event/room names.

Also those event's are listenable by user too.

```js
io.on('connect', onConnect);
function onConnect(socket) {
    socket.on('error', onError);
    socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);
    // ... and others too.

    // You can see and console on ping/pong events too.
    socket.on('ping', console.log);
    socket.on('pong', console.log);
}
```

I know socke.io's documentation really is not the best :D

By the way, ping and pong usage is coming from `ws` which also used by socket.io internally. If you want to see more about i'll leave links here where you can see `ping` and `pong` events emitting.

[Sender.js: ping](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/sender.js#L160) also Receiver.js: [ping](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/receiver.js#L477) & [pong](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/receiver.js#L479)